# How to configure better errors rails for firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext3, better-errors-gem

how to configure better errors for ROR on linux with firefox. Better errors gem is useful to open rails application error file with line number from browser only, so it will be less time consuming for developer to correct the error and no need to search file and line separately

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all download and install sublime url handler patch to handle the url with line number. Download [sublime-url-handler](https://github.com/algorich/sublime-url-handler/archive/master.zip).
2. Goto to development.rb file and add BetterErrors.editor = :sublime
3. Goto firefox and type about:config in url and hit enter
4. Right click and create new property with boolean type with name " network.protocol-handler.expose.subl" set "False".
5. Restart firefox.
6. Run your rails app and get the error link page, click on error link it will ask open open with if sublime-url-hanlder is shown here well done choose and cheers if not shown than give your sublime executable path here and done.

Remember give sublime executable path only not /usr/bin/subl, or shared lib path. You can find the executable path by running subl and see the process details like "ps -eaf | grep subl" copy the path and give this path in firefox choose application.